# Regarding Informatica power center server Installation

Tags: informatica

I have tried to install Informatica power center 10.1 on my PC. It gives me an message that it is not compatible.
Can I install Informatica power center 10 on Windows 10 Home Single language edition?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message you get ? In the Product Availability Matrix, only "Windows Server 2016 or 2019 Enterprise Edition including Essentials, Standard and Datacenter Editions (ALL SPs)" are supported. See https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/DOC-19597?language=en_US (You may need to create an account)